# print "message", var = raw_input()

Tags: python, python-2.7, printing

```
print "Question?",
answer = raw_input()
```

The error:

```
    Brians-Air:PythonFiles Ghost$ python ex11.py
  File "ex11.py", line 1
    print "How old are you?
                          ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

I removed the "," and the interpreter gave an error. My thought was that removing the "," would give a new-line and request input on this new-line.

My question is why is the "," after the print statement necessary? Is this just the syntax coded into Python?

Comment: The error was not caused by removing the comma and the effect is exactly as you described.

Comment: "the interpreter gave an error" _what was the error?_ We're not mind readers.

Comment: my bad!
Edits above.

Comment: can u show your full code..??

Comment: You're just missing the closing `"` (quote) of the string.

Answer (score 0):

here is what you need to write:

```
while True:
    print 'Question?'
    answer = raw_input('    >')
    if answer == ('done'):
        break
    print answer
```